# Javascript export/import class

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, export, babeljs

Why is this example below not outputting "hello world"?  Instead, I am getting:

> TypeError: _base2.default.test is not a function

(it is being transpiled with Babel)

**file1.js**

```
import Example from './file2';
console.log(Example.test());
```

**file2.js**

```
export default class Example {
  test() {
    console.log('hello world');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are only importing the class, but not making an instance of the class

Try

```
var myInstance = new Example()
myInstance.test()
```

Answer (score 23):

If you want to call a method as a class method (without creating an object instance) you can try static methods.

You can change the **file2.js** as,

```
export default class Example {
  static test() {
    console.log('hello world');
  }
}
```

then call it by using the class name in **file1.js** as

```
import Example from './file2';
console.log(Example.test());
```

Refer [James Maa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46356831/4791970) answer if you want to call it as an instance method.